# $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has at least one root in $(0,1)$ if $\frac{a}{m+2}+\frac{b}{m+1}+\frac{c}m=0$, with $m>0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

### Problem

Let $m, a, b, c \in \Bbb R$ and $m > 0$ so that the following equation holds: $$\frac{a}{m+2}+\frac{b}{m+1} + \frac{c}m = 0$$ Prove that the polynomial equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has at least ONE root between $(0,1)$.

#### Thought process

After a while, I was completely stuck. I tried solving $m$ in terms of $a,b,c$ but couldn't simplify them into any practical form. Then, I messed around with the roots, but I got many inequalities that were somewhat helpful. The original problem did not include any hints, and I had yet thought of any other paths (I was thinking about posting my partial solution here, but I am still very new to the formatting). I hope you can give me a little hint about what I should focus on, thank you very much! Have a wonderful day!

Comment: Hi Jack! I've added an answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: That is an amazing observation! Thank you very much :D

Comment: Here's an interesting variant of your problem. Suppose the condition $$\displaystyle\frac{a}{m+2}+\frac{b}{m+1}+\frac{c}m=0$$ is replaced with
$$\frac{5a+2b+c}{2a+b+c} = e$$ where $e$ is Euler's number. Can you still show that $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ has a root in $(0,1)$?

Comment: This is a strange theorem! What kind of class was it proposed in or what book?

Comment: I doubt the correctness of the question, or maybe I did not understand it correctly. Let $p(x)=x^{2}-x+0.25=(x-1/2)(x-1/2)$. Applying the condition on p(x), we get $\frac{1}{\left(t+2\right)}-\frac{1}{\left(t+1\right)}+\frac{1}{4t}$ which has no real value for $t$. Maybe the question should be: IF $\frac{1}{\left(t+2\right)}+\frac{1}{\left(t+1\right)}+\frac{1}{t}$ THEN $ax^2+bx+c$ has a root in $(0,1)$?

Comment: I have a little concern: This works for $m = 1$ but we want to show this for all $m$. However, substituting $m \ne 1$ into the original function yields a different polynomial. Is there something I had missed? Thank you very much =D

Comment: @NoChance I do think the problem is correct as it strictly specified $m > 0$. We cannot pick $a = 1, b = -1, c = \frac14$ as it violates the condition.

Comment: @JackNguyen, thanks for clarifying this.

Answer (score 4):

Consider $$f(x) := ax^{m+1} + bx^m + cx^{m-1}$$
The condition $\displaystyle\frac{a}{m+2}+\frac{b}{m+1}+\frac{c}m=0$ is equivalent to
$$\int_0^1 f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x = 0$$
By the [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) for definite integrals, there exists $x_0\in (0,1)$ such that $\int_0^1 f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x = f(x_0)$, i.e., $f(x_0) = 0$. Therefore, $ax_0^{m+1} + bx_0^m + cx_0^{m-1} = 0$ which implies $ax_0^2 + bx_0 + c = 0$ as $x_0 > 0$.

Comment: The mean value theorem for integrals says that: $\int _a^b\:f\left(x\right)dx=f\left(c\right)\left(b-a\right)$ not as you propose (ref:https://wonderfulworldofcalulus.weebly.com/mean-value-theorem-and-average-value-on-an-interval.html) Also, the OP used a quadratic equation specifically whereas you used an equation of power $m$ - Could you please explain in some details'? Thanks.